# Discrimination on the basis of profession

Tags: single-word-requests

I was wondering if there is any particular word for 'discrimination on the basis of profession/professional rank'.

Comment: Can you elaborate, and provide some examples? I can think of two: _"He must not be very smart; he's just a janitor,"_ or _"He can't be honest, he's a lawyer,"_ but it's hard to tell if your driving at that, or something else.

Comment: Is this just a form of snobbery?

Comment: How about _condescension, haughtiness, loftiness, lordliness, patronization, superciliousness, contempt, disdain, egotism, haughtiness, pomposity, presumptuousness, hubris, self-importance, snobbishness, vanity_?

Comment: There are other words for discrimination, such as *prejudice* or *snobbery* but none that could be used in the way you appear to seek. I think you'd need to be more specific about the context in which you intend to use the word.

Comment: I think that J.R. has pretty well pegged this OP's point. I did that once ("You're just an X, but I'm a Y": really the only words I have ever regretted uttering besides "I do" a couple of times) and had to wait 35 years to apologize to the person I did it to.

Comment: @BillFranke: It's worth noting that these kinds of faulty assumptions could go the other way around, too. _"He's a priest, so he must be honest,"_ e.g., or, _"She's a schoolteacher, so she must have a lot of patience around kids."_ This isn't always rooted in a spirit of haughtiness; it could be due to misplaced awe, too.

Comment: @J.R.: Good point! Positive discrimination and stereotyping.

Comment: There's also *rankism* http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rankism

Comment: _Elitism_ is a hypernym, covering family class, wealth, professional and religious status, looks...

Comment: Maybe it is referring to something like this: in a legal case about malpractice, if someone on the jury panel is a physician, then one of the lawyers will want him excluded.

Comment: You could suffix 'ism' to 'profession' or another appropriate word. Academic writers and others do it all the time. There is no doubt that your readers will comprehend 'professionism'.

Answer (score 1):

I think words like [***Rankism***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rankism) or [***Classism***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_discrimination) may fit your bill.

Wikipedia defines them as:

**Rankism**  *is "abusive, discriminatory, or exploitative behavior towards people because of their rank in a particular hierarchy*".

**Classism** *is prejudice or discrimination on the basis of social class. It includes individual attitudes and behaviors, systems of policies and practices that are set up to benefit the upper classes at the expense of the lower classes.*

Answer (score 0):

Not a single word, but *professional snobbery* describes exactly that.

Comment: Hard to make much of a living as a professional snob. :)

Comment: @tchrist: I guess you'll have to stick with professional slob. That's where the big bucks are anyways.